# Implementing automatic loop for each item and display only one image at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Deployed sample app http://fruit-items.herokuapp.com/

Code https://github.com/tenzan/catalog

I'd like to implement something like in the image:

1. On the left side listing up all items (*done*)
2. Loop a hover (a rectangle shape) on each item, and show image for an item that has a hovered rectangle. It should loop rectangle through items infinitely and it stays for 2 seconds on each item. User won't do any clicks. It should be automatically looping and showing corresponding image. (*not implemented yet*)

*index.html.erb*:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="floatleft">
      <% @items.each do |item| %>
         <ul><%= item.name %></ul>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="floatright"></div>
      // new code will come here?
    <div style="clear: both;">
</div>
```

Please give me the hint where and how to implement this.

I guess this can be done with jquery. Also interesting to know if this something easier to implement with vue.js or other UI frameworks.

[image]

Comment: Can you include `javascript` tried at Question?

Comment: There are a million ways to accomplish this. Search for “slider” or “carousel”.

Comment: @coreyward Thanks. If I'm not mistaken slider/carousel shows only one item at a time. In my case I want to show up all items but only one image that corresponds to that specific item with hovered rectangle.

Comment: Le sigh. You're going to have a helluva time writing code with zero curiosity or willingness to explore.